# Nginx SSL/Subdomain/IP redirect

Tags: nginx, centos7

at the moment I am running a website in 
**nginx/1.6.3** on **centOS7**

Everything runs smooth, except some redirects.

This is what my .conf file looks like:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy default deferred;
  server_name .example.com;

  ... more configs

  }


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name .example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

What I would like to accomplish are the following scenarios:

```
user visits in browser              | this should happen
------------------------------------|-------------------------------------
https://example.com$request_uri     | Just deliver content
https://*.example.com$request_uri   | 301 https://example.com$request_uri
https://123.123.123.123$request_uri | 301 https://example.com$request_uri
http://example.com$request_uri      | 301 https://example.com$request_uri
http://*.example.com$request_uri    | 301 https://example.com$request_uri
http://123.123.123.123$request_uri  | 301 https://example.com$request_uri
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check running with following config, this should work.

```
#This would serve all your content.
server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy default deferred;
  server_name example.com;

  ... more configs

}

#https calls to anything except example.com would be redirected here    
server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy default deferred; #(Can also use only : "listen 443;")
  server_name *.example.com 123.123.123.123;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

#All port 80 redirection to https://example.com
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com *.example.com 123.123.123.123;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this pattern to solve a similar problem:

```
server_name   ~^(?<subdomains>.+\.)?(?<domain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)$;
if ($domain != 'example.com') {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$  http://${subdomains}example.com/$1  permanent;
}
```

And so on